# How to change the format of the cell in Excel COM to Text

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am using VB.NET to write an Excel Worksheet. I need to write the value **3E01** but it always returns **3.00E+01**.

There is one easy way to write it by prepending single quote on the text but it will alter the value that is why I need it to format the cell value into Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the cell as text before you put the value in it:

```
theCell.NumberFormat = "@"
theCell.Value = "3E01"
```

where `theCell` is a reference you have to the cell.